# rpmbuild issue CentOS 6.6 - "rpmbuild -bp" exit 0 but no image file output

Tags: rpmbuild

the CentOS documentation says my new kernel will be in the 
rpmbuild/RPMS/`uname -m`/ directory, but the RPMS directory is totally empty, even though the rpmbuild ended with exit 0. 
The command I used was: 
    rpmbuild -bp --target=$(uname -m) kernel.spec

PS. (arch=s390x)

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`-bp` option only completes the `%prep` stage. Try changing it to `-ba` to "build all."

Ref: [rpm.org](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/ch-rpm-b-command.html)